# save image to the gallery after taken from the camera

Tags: android, flutter, storage, imagepicker

I use this code to take a picture with the plugin image_picker:

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

Now I would like to save the image in the gallery directory of the device.

According to the accepted answer to this post [How to Save Image File in Flutter ? File selected using Image_picker plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338041/how-to-save-image-file-in-flutter-file-selected-using-image-picker-plugin), it should have been done automatically, but I do not find in the gallery the picture taken.

I already added this permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: If you can pick an image file with an image picker then the image file is already on your device. Why would you make a copy of it?

Comment: `I use this code to take a picture with the plugin image_picker:` To take a picture? Or to pick an image? Quite confusing. Is that opening the camera app?

Comment: Is this on Android Q?

Comment: What is the value of image.path?

Comment: `I would like to save the image in the gallery directory of the device` What do you consider to be the gallery directory of the device? The Gallery app shows images from all over your device.

Comment: If you dont see the new image directly in the Gallery app then reboot your device.

Comment: @blackapps I take a picture from the camera, but i am not able to save it to the gallery

Comment: I still dont know what you mean by saving to the gallery but then you did not post any code. And you are not answering my questions.

Comment: @blackapps I mean the gallery of the device, not in the folder of the app. For the path of the image I will answer to you tonight.

Comment: What is the gallery of the device? `The Gallery app shows images from all over your device.`

Comment: In android devices you have the "Gallery" with the images you have in the device.

Comment: As i already told you twice there is only a Gallery app which shows images from all over the device. The Gallery app is now often Fotos/Photos app from google. Now the question for the third time: "Where do you wanna store that image?".

Comment: @blackapps these comments come to nothing, we can end. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use package gallery_saver https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver 
Get image with `ImagePicker` and save with `GallerySaver.saveImage`

code snippet

```
void _takePhoto() async {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedImage) {
      if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
        setState(() {
          firstButtonText = 'saving in progress...';
        });
        GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path, albumName: albumName)
            .then((bool success) {
          setState(() {
            firstButtonText = 'image saved!';
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String firstButtonText = 'Take photo';
  String secondButtonText = 'Record video';
  double textSize = 20;
  String albumName ='Media';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: _takePhoto,
                    child: Text(firstButtonText,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: textSize, color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: _recordVideo,
                  child: Text(secondButtonText,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: textSize, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                ),
              )),
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _takePhoto() async {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedImage) {
      if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
        setState(() {
          firstButtonText = 'saving in progress...';
        });
        GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path, albumName: albumName)
            .then((bool success) {
          setState(() {
            firstButtonText = 'image saved!';
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _recordVideo() async {
    ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedVideo) {
      if (recordedVideo != null && recordedVideo.path != null) {
        setState(() {
          secondButtonText = 'saving in progress...';
        });
        GallerySaver.saveVideo(recordedVideo.path, albumName: albumName)
            .then((bool success) {
          setState(() {
            secondButtonText = 'video saved!';
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _saveNetworkVideo() async {
    String path =
        'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4';
    GallerySaver.saveVideo(path, albumName: albumName).then((bool success) {
      setState(() {
        print('Video is saved');
      });
    });
  }

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _saveNetworkImage() async {
    String path =
        'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/montreal-canada-july-11-2019-600w-1450023539.jpg';
    GallerySaver.saveImage(path, albumName: albumName).then((bool success) {
      setState(() {
        print('Image is saved');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What would be a/the value of `recordedImage.path` ?

Comment: recordedImage.path is the path image picker temporary save these files.

Comment: Yes. Please give an example of the value of such a path was the question. Where exactly is it stored?

Comment: You can print path. because in ios, android , emulator, they all different example is /data/0/emulated/your_app/cache

Comment: Thanks. I asked as i have no Flutter and @Giacomo M is strugling. I wonder if he is aware that there is a file already. He did not give the value for image.path.