# How do I get an Image from a List<int> holding the images bytecode?

Tags: image, flutter, mobile, uint8list

I have a piece of code where I am covering an image into a List in order to store it in the device's memory. I then pull this list back out and would like to use it. I am current;y using `MemoryImage(bytes)` where bytes is the variable for List. There is currently no error being thrown however, the image does not show up regardless. Is there a better method for this action?

Comment: can you tell is this a network image loaded via a URL or a capture image?

Comment: This is an Image gotten with the Image_picker tool and being kept as a File variable.

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51338178/2043275

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! After I reworked my code to fit that answer I was able to save the image. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution given in the comments from thusith.92 was a correct solution. Instead of placing the image into the database, I stored the path of the image and simply used the systems built-in storage.