# Image storing in shared preferences in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, memory, sharedpreferences, store

How can we store image in shared preferences and retrieve from shared preferences in flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338041/how-to-save-image-file-in-flutter-file-selected-using-image-picker-plugin

Give this a try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Save Image File in Flutter ? File selected using Image\_picker plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338041/how-to-save-image-file-in-flutter-file-selected-using-image-picker-plugin)

Answer (score 10):

You can convert the Image to Unit8List then convert UnitList8 to base64 and save it. Here is an example.

```
static Future<bool> saveImage(List<int> imageBytes) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
    return prefs.setString("image", base64Image);
  }

  static Future<Image> getImage() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(prefs.getString("image"));
    return Image.memory(bytes);
  }
```

Then use it.

From Assets

```
 ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/file');
  SharedPreferencesHelper.saveImage(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
```

From Network

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
    'https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png',
  );
  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    SharedPreferencesHelper.saveImage(response.bodyBytes);
  }else{
    //TODO: Handle error
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly know the solution with shared preferences but I was doing that with path_provider like just this;

for saving to disk;

```
Future<bool> saveNetworkImageToDisk() async{
await fileController.prepareInSubDirectoryJsonFile();
try{
  var response=await get(this.imageUrl); //http package for geting image from the internet 
  if(response.statusCode==200){
    await fileController.file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}catch(e){
  return false;
}
```

}

for getting from disk;

```
  Future<File> getImage() async{
    Future<File> getImage() async{
    await fileController.prepareInSubDirectoryJsonFile();
    return fileController.file;
  }
```

in file_controller.dart prepareJsonFileFunction doing this:
you need just;

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

String directory=await  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((appDirectory){return appDirectory;});
String appPath=directory.path;
file=File('${this.appPath}/${this.fileName}');
```

Also I am doing this works in try-catch system, so you can modify them :)