# How to save the photos taken with image_picker in flutter to the phone

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm confused I've taken a picture but can't save it to the phone.How should I save pictures to the phone?

I used the following code to take a picture.

```
ValueNotifier<XFile?>_imageFile=ValueNotifier(null);
```

ImagePicker _imagePicker=ImagePicker();

```
Future<void> _getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async{
    XFile? imgFile=await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
    _imageFile.value=imgFile;
  }
```

Comment: There is an answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51338178/11690853

Comment: Thanks.Yes, I know this. But I get an error when I type it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another aproach to save your picked image:

```
final XFile? pickedFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
new File(pathToSaveHere).writeAsBytesSync(await pickedFile!.readAsBytes());
```

about "pathToSaveHere" you can use "`path_provider`" plugin of [flutter https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider](https://flutter%20https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider). It provide severeal methods to get paths you are able to save. Note that: **due permissions restrictions you CANNOT save everywhere**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does pathToSaveHere is what I need to give a path?

Answer (score 0):

First add gallery_saver package then call this function,

```dart
void _takePhoto() async {
    final _pickedImg= await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: 
       ImageSource.camera)
         .then((File recordedImage) {
            // saving the picked Image to Gallery
            if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
            GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path);
            setState(() {});
      }});
   // ur picked image in File form 
   File? img = File(_pickedImg!.path);
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused what pickedImageFile is. It appears in error when I type it inside my vscode.Also,yes, i wanna save the pic to the Gallery.How should i use "gallery_saver" package?

Comment: ohh um sorry i couldn't edit. its  File? _pickedImage = File(img!.path) . Search on youtube, "how to save image to gallery in flutter"

Comment: I'm still confused about saving pictures to gallery. The examples I found are all to save a specific picture, but I want to save the picture I just took with image_picker to the gallery.

Comment: Got it. updated my comment. check it out

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got the following error message：The argument type 'Null Function(File)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(XFile?)'.How should I solve it.