# How to save images from the camera into gallery when captured in flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, imagepicker, save-image

How can I save images when I capture it ?
I am using ImagePicker and just know how to preview it, but not how to save it.
Is there any way that we can take multiple images at one time and then click OK,
It would come back to the screen, show and automatic save them to gallery?

```
Future _takeImageFromCamera() async {
    final returnedImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (returnedImage == null) return;
    setState(() {
      _selectedImage = File(returnedImage!.path);
    });
  }
```

I already search on youtube and stackOverFlow but they save images from the url not what i want to

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338041/how-to-save-image-file-in-flutter-file-selected-using-image-picker-plugin